# Deck shuffling in C will compile but Segmentation Faults

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, enums, segmentation-fault

```
typedef enum {Clubs = 1, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades} suit_t;
typedef enum {Ace = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Five = 5,
              Six = 6, Seven = 7, Eight = 8, Nine = 9, Ten = 10,
              Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13} face_t;

typedef struct card_t
{
        suit_t suit;
        face_t face;
} card;

typedef struct stack_t
{
    struct card_t deck[53];
    int size;
} stack_h;

void shuffle_deck(stack_h *stack)
{
   stack_h temp, *cardptr;
   int i,num;

   for(i = 0; i < stack->size; i++)
   {
    i = rand() %stack->size;
    *cardptr = *stack;
    temp = *cardptr;
    *cardptr = *stack;
    *stack = temp;
   }
}
```

So I have tried many different ways to make my deck shuffle but unfortunately I have had no luck what I am trying to do is well shuffle the deck it compiles but when it gets shuffling the deck it'll segmentation fault. Any ideas on how to fix it? Everything works but the shuffling function.

Comment: Have you done a stack trace?  Also, when posting a question, try to only post the relevant code.  `shuffle_deck` in this case.  It makes it much easier for people to see when they don't have to look through all of your other code.

Comment: In shuffle, you are assigning a random integer to your stack `*stack = rand() %stack->size;` -- I don't think that's what you intend.

Comment: @dubstylee Thanks I didn't really know what I needed to include

Comment: @user590028 You're right but what do I do with the int I assign?

Comment: @dubstylee Oh and no I have no idea what that is

Comment: @CodeHero There is a very helpful tool called GDB that you can use to run a stack trace on a coredump.  When you get a segmentation fault, depending on your settings, you may get a coredump file that you can use to run some diagnostics and see what is actually causing the program to crash.

Comment: Your code performs various manipulations on `stack`, but it looks like what you want to be manipulating are the elements of `stack->deck`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes but when I change the *stack to stack->deck it says that they are incompatible types when assigning

Comment: I see you have a deck of 53 cards, presumably because you refer to them as index `1..52`. It is better to *work* with 0-based representations and convert for human consumption at the point of input/output. So if a `card` has a value `0..51` its `suit` will be `card/13` and its `rank` will be `card%13`, with arrays to present them to the user with `suit` and `rank` also 0-based.

Comment: Well yes, because the elements of `stack->deck` have type `card_t`.  If you want to assign the value of such an element to another variable, say `temp`, then that variable must also have type `card_t`.

Comment: Is the fifty-third card in the deck an extra Ace of Spades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first the algorithm.  There are various ways to perform a shuffle, but a common technique (Fisher-Yates) is:

1. If there are fewer than two elements remaining to be shuffled then stop.
2. Select a random element from the pool of those remaining to be shuffled, and swap it with the last element of the pool.
3. Reduce the size of the pool by one, and go back to step 1.

An implementation of that in C might look like this:

```
void shuffle_deck(stack_h *stack)
{
   int last;

   for (last = stack->size - 1; last > 0; last -= 1)
   {
      int i = rand() % (last + 1);

      if (i < last) {
          card_t temp = stack->deck[i];
          stack->deck[i] = stack->deck[last];
          stack->deck[last] = temp;
      } // else the chosen element is already in the target position
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that that assumes the valid elements of `stack->deck` to be those from index `0` to index `stack->size - 1`.

Comment: This gives me an idea of what I need to do thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
*cardptr = *stack;
```

happens before the variable `cardptr` is made to point to anything, therefore it points to random memory, which you overwrite.

Shuffling is a well-known solved problem. Google "Fisher-Yates".

Answer (score 0):

Your swapping code is dubious at best.  It might be more nearly correct to use:

```
for (i = 0; i < stack->size; i++)
{
    int j = rand() % stack->size;
    card_t temp = stack->deck[i];
    stack->deck[i] = stack->deck[j];
    stack->deck[j] = temp;
}
```

This probably isn't an unbiassed shuffle.  See [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) at Wikipedia and also [The Danger of Naïveté](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) on Coding Horror.